# Определение версии ОС на Windows 8.1 и выше

Tags: winapi, ос

В документации Microsoft описана функция GetVersion(), позволяющая получить версию текущей ОС. Однако на версии 8.1 и выше функция объявлена как "deprecated", т.к. возвращает не верный результат, в связи с чем рекомендуется использовать "Version helper functions" по типу IsWindowsXXXOrGreater(). Но эти функции совсем не заменяют GetVersion(), т.к. не позволяют узнать "подверсию", билд и другие характеристики, а лишь возвращают "да/нет". Значит, они не подойдут (либо я чего-то не понимаю).

Кроме этого, я нашёл ещё два варианта решения проблемы: вызывать RtlGetVersion() - аналог GetVersion() в режиме ядра, либо подключать манифест к проекту. Ни того, ни другого я не добился несмотря на долгие поиски. В сети очень много дискуссий на эти темы, но ни одна из них не покрывает проблему настолько полно, чтобы лично мне было понятно. Рассчитываю, что здесь для меня приведут пример хотя бы одного из способов.

P.S. Касаемо подключения манифеста: конкретное описание того, что я не понял.

С каким расширением должен быть файл-манифест? .xml? .manifest? .exe.manifest?

Подключать манифест к проекту нужно как самостоятельный ресурс или к определённому файлу с ресурсами?

Что за блок с заголовком "syntax" [в документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/sysinfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1) и куда и как включать его содержимое?

Comment: Попробуйте WMI, `Win32_OperatingSystem.Version`. Ну ещё может там же ServicePackMajorVersion/ServicePackMinorVersion.

Comment: Это для C#, как я понял? Если да, то мне необходимо использовать лишь нативный WinAPI.

Comment: Да хоть из чего... [Win32_OperatingSystem class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вариант с использованием RtlGetVersion():

```
int main()
{
    NTSTATUS(WINAPI *RtlGetVersion)(LPOSVERSIONINFOEXW);
    OSVERSIONINFOEXW osInfo;

    *(FARPROC*)&RtlGetVersion = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "RtlGetVersion");

    if (NULL != RtlGetVersion)
    {
        osInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osInfo);
        RtlGetVersion(&osInfo);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Так же можно получить эту информацию из WMI, но это более затратный по времени и коду метод.